# R conditional replace more columns by lookup

Tags: r, dataframe, lookup, na

Lets say we do have lots of data columns (with names **mycols** and also some unnamed ones that should not be processed in this case) in dataframe **df1** and a column **subj** which is also an index to another dataframe **df2** with columns **repl** and **subj** (in this second dataframe is **subj** unique) and much other nonimportant columns (their only role in this is, that we cannot suppose that there are just 2 columns).

I would like to replace a subset of columns ( **df1[,mycols]** ) in such a way, that if there is an **NA** ( **df1[,mycols][is.na(df1[,mycols])]** ) <- replace by a value of column **df2$repl** where the row in **df2** has **df2$subj = df1$subj**.

EDIT: example data (I dont know the command to write it as dataframe assignment):

```
mycols = c("a","b")
df1:
subj a  b  c
1    NA NA 1
1    2  3  5
2    0  NA 2
3    8  8  8
df2:
subj repl notinterested
1     5    1000
2     6    0
3     40   10
result:
df1-transformed-to:
subj a  b  c
1    5  5  1      #the 2 fives appeared by lookup
1    2  3  5
2    0  6  2     #the 6 appeared
3    8  8  8
```

I came up with the following code:

```
df1[,mycols][is.na(df1[,mycols])] <- df2[match( df1$subj, df2$subj),"repl"]
```

But the problem is (I think), that the right side is not the same size as the left side - I think it might work for one column in "**mycols**", but I want to do the same operation with all **mycols** (If **NA**, look to table **df2** and replace - the replacing value is the same in the scope of the row).

(Also I need to enumerate the columns by names **mycols** explicitely everythime, because there might be another columns)

*As a miniquestion as bonus about programming style* - what is, in R, a good and a fast way to write this operation? If it would be a procedural language, we could transform

```
df1[,mycols][is.na(df1[,mycols])]
```

into an approach I consider more nice and more readable:

```
function(x){ *x[is.na(*x)] }
function(& df1[,mycols])
```

and being sure, that nothing gets unnecessarily copied from place to place.

Comment: Added example of dataprocessing, thx for comment!

Comment: @akrun Iam a noob in R so Iam unfortunately not able to understand how it could work, can You make it please an answer?

Comment: I added a solution based on your code and corrected it.

Comment: Thanks! BTW all the responses are great, guys, so I have accepted the one with lapply :)

Comment: Edit - akrun won - the longest and coolest answer :)

Comment: The story has a continuation by more difficult setting and indexing to range: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564834/r-replacing-columns-by-lookup-to-dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your code, we need to `replicate` the 'repl' column to make the two subset datasets equal and then assign the values as you did

```
 val <- df2$repl[match(df1$subj, df2$subj)][row(df1[mycols])][is.na(df1[mycols])]
 df1[mycols][is.na(df1[mycols])] <- val
 df1
 #  subj a b c
 #1    1 5 5 1
 #2    1 2 3 5
 #3    2 0 6 2
 #4    3 8 8 8
```

Another option using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 DT <- setDT(df1, key='subj')[df2[c('subj', 'repl')]]
 for(j in mycols){
   i1 <- which(is.na(DT[[j]]))
   set(DT, i=i1, j=j, value= DT[['repl']][i1])
   }
 DT[,repl:= NULL]
 #   subj a b c
 #1:    1 5 5 1
 #2:    1 2 3 5
 #3:    2 0 6 2
 #4:    3 8 8 8
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 left_join(df1, df2, by='subj') %>%
        mutate_each_(funs(ifelse(is.na(.),repl,.)), mycols) %>% 
        select(a:c)
 #  a b c
 #1 5 5 1
 #2 2 3 5
 #3 0 6 2
 #4 8 8 8
```

#### data

```
 df1 <-  structure(list(subj = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), a = c(NA, 2L, 0L, 8L 
 ), b = c(NA, 3L, NA, 8L), c = c(1L, 5L, 2L, 8L)), .Names = c("subj", 
 "a", "b", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

 df2 <- structure(list(subj = 1:3, repl = c(5L, 6L, 40L),
 notinterested = c(1000L, 
 0L, 10L)), .Names = c("subj", "repl", "notinterested"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution using [`ifelse()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html):

```
mycols <- c('a','b');
df1 <- data.frame(subj=c(1,1,2,3), a=c(NA,2,0,8), b=c(NA,3,NA,8), c=c(1,5,2,8) );
df2 <- data.frame(subj=c(1,2,3), repl=c(5,6,40), notinterested=c(1000,0,10) );
df1[mycols] <- ifelse(is.na(df1[mycols]),matrix(df2[match(df1$subj,df2$subj),'repl'],nrow(df1),length(mycols)),as.matrix(df1[mycols]));
df1;
##   subj a b c
## 1    1 5 5 1
## 2    1 2 3 5
## 3    2 0 6 2
## 4    3 8 8 8
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this with base R:

```
mycols = c("a","b")
df1 <- read.table(text="subj a  b  c
1    NA NA 1
1    2  3  5
2    0  NA 2
3    8  8  8", header = TRUE)
df2 <- read.table(text="subj repl notinterested
1     5    1000
2     6    0
3     40   10", header = TRUE)
df1[mycols] <- lapply(df1[mycols], function(x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- df2$repl[match(df1$subj[is.na(x)], df2$subj)]; x})
```