# R replacing columns by lookup to dictionary

Tags: r, dataframe, lookup, na

In this question I need to be able to lookup a value from a dataframe's column not only based on one attribute, but based on more attributes and range comparing against a dictionary.
(Yes, this is actually a continuation of a story in [R conditional replace more columns by lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045512/r-conditional-replace-more-columns-by-lookup) )

It should be easy question for R-known ppl, because I provide working solution for basic indexing, that needs to be upgraded, possibly easily ... but it is very hard for me, because Iam in a process of learning R.

**From where to start:**

When I do want to replace missing values from columns **testcolnames** from (big) table **df1** according to column **default** of (small) dictionary **testdefs** (row selected by making **testdefs$LABMET_ID** equal to column name from **testcolnames**), I use this code:

```
testcolnames=c("80","116") #...result of regexp on colnames(df1), originally much longer

df1[,testcolnames] <- lapply(testcolnames, function(x) { tmpcol<-df1[,x];
  tmpcol[is.na(tmpcol)] <- testdefs$default[match(x, testdefs$LABMET_ID)];
  tmpcol  })
```

**To where to go:**

Now - I need to upgrade this solution. The table **testdefs** will have (example below) multiple rows of the same **LABMET_ID** differing only by new two columns called **lower** and **upper** ... which need to be the bounds for variable **df1$rngvalue** when selecting which value to replace.

In another words - to upgrade this solution to not only select the row from **testdefs** (where **testdefs$LABMET_ID** equals the column name), but to select from these rows such a row, where **df1$rngvalue** is in the bounds of **testdefs$lower** and **testdefs$upper** (*if none such exists, take the range closest - either the lowest or the highest, if the dictionary doesnt have LABMET_ID, we can leave NA in the original data*).

An example:

**testdefs**

```
"LABMET_ID","lower","upper","default","notuse","notuse2"
30,0,54750,25,80,2            #..."many columns we dont care about"
46,0,54750,1.45,3.5,0.2
80,0,54750,0.03,0.1,0.01
116,0,30,0.09,0.5,0.01
116,31,365,0.135,0.7,0.01
116,366,5475,0.11,0.7,0.01
116,5476,54750,0.105,0.7,0.02
```

**df1:**

```
"rngvalue","80","116"
36,NA,NA
600000,NA,NA
367,5,NA
90,NA,6
```

**to be transformed into:**

```
"rngvalue","80","116"
36,0.03,0.135                   #col80 is always replaced by 0.03
600000,0.03,0.105               #col116 needs to be decided on range, this value is bigger than everything in dictionary so take the last one
367,5,0.11                      #5 not replaced, but second column nicely looks up to 0.11
90,0.03,6                       #6 not replaced
```

Comment: are the intervals always consecutive like "116", ie (31-365, 366-5475, 5476-54750, etc) and without gaps?

Comment: Yes they are! Iam sorry to forget to mention :) Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the intervals don't have gaps, you can use `findInterval`.  I would change the lookup table to a list containing the break points and defaults for each value using `dlply` from `plyr`.

```
## Transform lookup table to a list with breaks for intervals
library(plyr)
lookup <- dlply(testdefs, .(LABMET_ID), function(x)
    list(breaks=c(rbind(x$lower, x$upper), x$upper[length(x$upper)])[c(T,F)],
         default=x$default))
```

So, the lookups now look like

```
lookup[["116"]]
# $breaks
# [1]     0    31   366  5476 54750
# 
# $default
# [1] 0.090 0.135 0.110 0.105
```

Then, you can do the lookup with the following

```
testcolnames=c("80","116")

df1[,testcolnames] <- lapply(testcolnames, function(x) {
    tmpcol <- df1[,x]
    defaults <- with(lookup[[x]], {
        default[pmax(pmin(length(breaks)-1, findInterval(df1$rngvalue, breaks)), 1)]
    })
    tmpcol[is.na(tmpcol)] <- defaults[is.na(tmpcol)]
    tmpcol
})

#   rngvalue   80   116
# 1       36 0.03 0.135
# 2   600000 0.03 0.105
# 3      367 5.00 0.110
# 4       90 0.03 6.000
```

The `findInterval` returns values below and above the number of breaks if the rngvalue is outside of the range.  That is the reason for the `pmin` and `pmax` in the code above.

Comment: Works like charm! I only needed to write there explicitely lookup[[x]] dont know why "with" was not working and to add ifelse if the replacement column was not present in the dictionary.